# Solving $\frac{2x}{5} + \frac{x}{7} + \frac{x}{3} + 26 = x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the fastest method to solve the following equation?

> $\frac{2x}{5} + \frac{x}{7} + \frac{x}{3} + 26 = x$

My thought is to **go by pairs** like the following:

$x\cdot(\frac{2}{5} + \frac{1}{7} ) + x \cdot (\frac{1}{3} - 1) = -26$
$\implies x \cdot\frac{2 \cdot 7 + 1 \cdot 5}{35} + x \cdot\frac{1 - 3}{3} = -26$
$\implies x \cdot \frac{19}{35} - \frac{2}{3} = -26$
$\implies x \cdot \frac{19\cdot3 - 2\cdot35}{35 \cdot 3} = -26$
$\implies x \cdot \frac{57-70}{35\cdot3} = -26$
$\implies x \cdot\frac{-13}{35 \cdot 3} = -26$
$\implies x = \frac{26\cdot35\cdot3}{13}$
$\implies x = 35\cdot6$
$\implies x = 210$

Is there any better technique where I can make this computation faster?

Comment: You can clear all the denominators on the LHS simultaneously: $(\frac25+\frac17+\frac13)x=(\frac{2\cdot7\cdot3}{5\cdot7\cdot3}+\frac{1\cdot5\cdot3}{5\cdot7\cdot3}+\frac{1\cdot5\cdot7}{5\cdot7\cdot3})x=\ldots$, but this is about the same effort as what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step I'd take is to multiply every term by $105$. Then, there are no fractions, and you can solve for $x$ in the usual way. For me, working by hand, this is fastest:

\begin{align}
42x+15x+35x+26\cdot 105 &=105x\\
92x+26\cdot 105 &= 105x\\
26\cdot 105 &= 13x\\
2\cdot 105 &= x
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2x(7)(3)}{5(7)(3)}+\frac{x(5)(3)}{7(5)(3)}+\frac{x(5)(7)}{3(5)(7)}+\frac{26(3)(5)(7)}{3(5)(7)}=\frac{x(3)(5)(7)}{(3)(5)(7)}$$
Denominators are the same so get rid.

Then:
$$42x+15x+35x+2730=105x$$
$$13x=2730\to x=210$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way:

Replace $x=0$, obviously the equation does not hold, so $x=0$ is eliminated.

So $x\ne 0$, we can now divide both sides by $x$:

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{2x}{5} + \dfrac{x}{7} + \dfrac{x}{3} + 26 = x &\Leftrightarrow \dfrac{2}{5}+\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{26}{x}=1 \\
&\Leftrightarrow \dfrac{92}{105}+\dfrac{26}{x}=1\\
&\Leftrightarrow \dfrac{26}{x}=\dfrac{13}{105}=\dfrac{13\times 2}{105\times 2}=\dfrac{26}{210}\\
&\Leftrightarrow x=210\\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

The step $\dfrac{2}{5} + \dfrac{1}{7} + \dfrac{1}{3}=\dfrac{92}{105}$ is still a bit time consuming however. For the second-to-last step, you should know that $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{a\times n}{b\times n}$ for positive integers $a,b,n$.